# Read SHP file from SFTP using pysftp

Tags: python, sftp, shapefile, pysftp

I am trying to use pysftp's `getfo()` to read a shapefile (without downloading it). However the output I get does not seem workable and I'm not sure if its possible do this with a shapefile.

Ideally I would like to read in the file and convert it to a Geopandas GeoDataFrame.

```
import pysftp
import io

with pysftp.Connection(host=host, username=user, password=pass) as sftp:
    print("Connection established ... ")

    flo = io.BytesIO()
    sites = sftp.getfo('sites/Sites.shp', flo)
    value=flo.getvalue()
```

From here I can't decode the value and am unsure of how to proceed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should do:

```
flo.seek(0)
df = geopandas.read_file(shp=flo)
```

---

Though using the `Connection.getfo` unnecessarily keeps whole raw file in memory. More efficient would be:

```
with sftp.open('sites/Sites.shp', bufsize=32768) as f:
    df = geopandas.read_file(f)
```

*(for the purpose of `bufsize=32768`, see [Reading file opened with Python Paramiko SFTPClient.open method is slow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58433996/850848))*

---

Though if I understand it correctly, you need multiple files. There's no way the geopandas can magically access other related files on a remote server, when you provide the "shp" via file-like object. Geopandas does not know, where does the "shp" come from or even what is its physical name. You need to provide file-like objects for all individual files. See [Using pyshp to read a file-like object from a zipped archive](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/250092) – they do not use Geopandas, but the principle is the same.

For Geopandas, it seems that underlying *fiona* library handles that and I didn't find any documentation of the relevant parameters.

I guess *something like this* might do, but that's just a wild guess:

```
with sftp.open('sites/Sites.shp', bufsize=32768) as shp,
     sftp.open('sites/Sites.shx', bufsize=32768) as shx:
     sftp.open('sites/Sites.dbf', bufsize=32768) as dbf:
     ...
    df = geopandas.read_file(shp, shx=shx, dbf=dbf, ...)
```

or switch to the [`shapefile`/`pyshp` module](https://pypi.org/project/pyshp/):

```
with sftp.open('sites/Sites.shp', bufsize=32768) as shp,
     sftp.open('sites/Sites.shx', bufsize=32768) as shx:
     sftp.open('sites/Sites.dbf', bufsize=32768) as dbf:
     ...
    r = shapefile.Reader(shp=shp, shx=shx, dbf=dbf)
```

Another trick is to pack all files to a zip archive:
[Read shapefile from HDFS with geopandas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66278161/850848)

---

Btw, note that the code *downloads* the file(s) anyway. You cannot parse a remote file contents, without actually *downloading* that file contents. The code just avoids storing the downloaded file contents to a (temporary) local file.