# Pyshp reading shapefile: "error: int too large to convert"

Tags: python, paramiko, shapefile, shapely, pysftp

Follow up from [Read SHP file from SFTP using pysftp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70447892/read-shp-file-from-sftp-using-pysftp) for more context.

I am trying to use pyshp and pysftp to read a shapefile and convert to a GeoPandas geodataframe. This has worked successfully for all files tested until the following error occurred.

Code:

```
from shapely.geometry import shape

r = shapefile.Reader(shp=shp, shx=shx, dbf=dbf)
fields = [field[0] for field in r.fields[1:]]

attributes = []
geometry = []

for row in r.shapeRecords():
     geometry.append(shape(row.shape.__geo_interface__))
     attributes.append(dict(zip(fields, row.record)))
```

Error:

```
~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\shapefile.py in __shape(self)
   1039         record = Shape()
   1040         nParts = nPoints = zmin = zmax = mmin = mmax = None
-> 1041         (recNum, recLength) = unpack(">2i", f.read(8))
   1042         # Determine the start of the next record
   1043         next = f.tell() + (2 * recLength)

~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\paramiko\file.py in read(self, size)

~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_file.py in _read(self, size)

~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.py in _request(self, t, *arg)

~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.py in _async_request(self, fileobj, t, *arg)

~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\paramiko\message.py in add_int64(self, n)

error: int too large to convert
```

Is there a way to convert this int or perform this in chunks to avoid the error? The file that caused the error is not especially large (<2MB).

Comment: To me it looks like the file is either corrupted or in a format not supported by the shapefile.

Answer (score 1):

The issue seemed to be the handling of NULL geometries in the shapefile.

While I don't fully understand why this caused an issue, according to the documentation ([here](https://pypi.org/project/pyshp/#reading-shapefiles)) pyshp "handles shapes with no coords and represent as geojson with no coords (GeoJSON null-equivalent)".

Skipping the null geoms when adding records to the 'attributes' and 'geometry' lists seemed to fix the error:

```
 fields = [field[0] for field in r.fields[1:]]
        
 attributes = []
 geometry = []

 for row in r.shapeRecords():
      if row.shape.shapeType == 0:
           continue
      else:
           geometry.append(shape(row.shape.__geo_interface__))
           attributes.append(dict(zip(fields, row.record)))
```

Not the most satisfactory solution but may be useful or someone may be able to elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

This maybe due to variable crosses sys max size. Check sys max size vs  variable size
using

```
import sys
sys.maxsize
```

Output I got

```
9223372036854775807
```

To check variable size

```
import sys
sys.getsizeof(r)
```

In order to fix this. Pls re declare Variable type to int64.

```
dtype=variable.int64
```

If this not solved the error pls, Let me know

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. `sys.getsizeof(r)` returns 48, which is expected as it is a small file.